# Rebase commits on remote branch

Tags: git, rebase

I forked a project on github, made a new branch and made some changes (commits B, C and D) so I had the following tree:

```
... <-- A                     (master)
         \
          B <-- C <-- D       (branch2)
```

I mistakenly merged and deleted `branch2` so now I had this tree:

```
... <-- A <-- B <-- C <-- D   (master)
```

However, I realized that I want to maintain a master branch that reflects the upstream changes and created myproject-master to have my work on that. I moved my commits by rebasing them to that new branch. After rebasing I deleted the `<-- B <-- C <-- D` part from the history on master by `git reset --hard "A"`. I also squased `C` and `D` and I'll refer to that commit as `CD` from now on. My problem is that I can't push my changes on master and I have different trees in local and remote:

This is the local tree (what I want to have on both sides):

```
... <-- A                     (master)
         \
          B <-- CD            (myproject-master)
```

This is the remote tree:

```
... <-- A <-- B <-- C <-- D   (master)
         \
          B <-- CD            (myproject-master)
```

When I try to push on master, git rejects the push so I don't lose data. Which is fine, but I already have those commits on the other branch and would like to clean them from the master. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the only person working on the repository, it's safe to do a "force push" of your master branch to the remote repository, e.g. with:

```
git checkout master
git push -f myrepo master
```

... but since that's rewriting the history of the master branch, you will have to be more careful if you have any collaborators who have already pulled your `master` when it was ahead of `A`.